# Building a real world Flutter app with Firebase and Stripe

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a full on mobile app using Flutter and have selected to use Firebase as the backend support.

So I've seen that Firebase docs and tutorials for Flutter are available for basic needs such as Authentication, CRUD and things alike. However, my app, like most others has nuanced features that the docs and tutorials do not cover, I was wondering if anyone has any resources (GitHub repos, videos, etc) that could be used to build features like the following:

User persistence
Friend's list
Group creation by selecting friend's from list
Making transaction posts (I'll use Stripe's API for transactions) in these private groups
I was unable to find resources that matched these features and before I started getting my hands dirty with building them from scratch myself I wanted to see if anyone here knew of any that I may not.

I've tried almost all youtube tutorials and code labs and things alike.

Thanks!

-

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing.
At first I recommend this course on Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps/ for the basics.

It will explain Flutter and Dart and their interaction with the Phone in detail and give you also some basics in Firebase Authentication. It's only like 10 bucks I'm 70% in and it's pure gold.

From there you can google or youtube the content that you need. StackOverflow, Youtube and Medium.com are your best info sources.